# Excel Web Access Error: At least one item has to be in filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, excel-web-access-webpart

I created a Pivot Table in Excel and then from that a chart is created.

I added a 'Excel Web Access' web part to display that chart in SharePoint.

[image]

Chart is displayed perfectly.
Now I need to filter this data according to 'Joining' column so I selected single value-

[image]

And when I hit 'OK' I got below error-

[image]

This does not make sense as I have selected one value. This error does not go away until and unless I choose all the values and hit OK.

I have tested this with different Charts and same problem occurs. But in Excel, Charts work fine.

Anyone has any idea what is happening here please share.

Comment: Why are there two columns for 2010 & 2014? What happens when you select one of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted with Microsoft guys through Office365 forums. They said it is a product level error and required my account information to roll out the update. Once they performed that update, this error was gone.